# Spring Boot AMQP Receiver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I'm creating a simple Spring Boot app that I want to receive messages sent to an AMQP (Rabbit) exchange (from another application).

I am getting an error stating that the queue i'm to receive on does not exists. When I look at http://localhost:15672/#/queues i can see that it does; i delete it before starting this application.

I read on another post that if a queue does not exists, RabbitAdmin has to be declared and declareExchange() and declareQueue() used to overcome this.
Even with this in place I'm still seeing the same error. Furthermore, the error is confusing b/c it states:

Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue '**from-logger-exchange**' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)

Note the 'no queue' indicates my exchange name.

Here's the configuration code (i realize that Boot creates the connectionFactory & RabbitAdmin but started adding these when that wasn't working):

```
'import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.FanoutExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Value("${spring.activemq.broker-url}")
    String host;
    @Value("${spring.activemq.user}")
    String userName;
    @Value("${spring.activemq.password}")
    String password;

    @Value("${config.exchangeName}")
    String exchangeName;

    @Value("${config.queueName}")
    String queueName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void printVariables() {
        System.out.println("host " + host);
        System.out.println("userName " + userName);
        System.out.println("password " + password);
        System.out.println("exchangeName " + exchangeName);
        System.out.println("queueName " + queueName);

        System.out.println("queue.name " + queue().getName());
        System.out.println("exchange.name " + topicExchange().getName());
        System.out.println("binding " + binding().toString());

        System.out.println("connectionFactory " + connectionFactory().toString());
        System.out.println("rabbitAdmin " + rabbitAdmin().toString());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(host);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(userName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin() {
        RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
        rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(topicExchange());
        rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue());
        return rabbitAdmin;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName);
    }

//  @Bean
//  public FanoutExchange fanoutExchange() {
//      return new FanoutExchange(exchangeName);
//  }

    public TopicExchange topicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(exchangeName, false, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        //return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(fanoutExchange());
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(topicExchange()).with("my.routing.key");
    }

    @Bean
    public Receiver receiver() {
        return new Receiver();
    }
}
```

'

Here's the Receiver:

```
    import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;

public class Receiver {

    @RabbitListener(queues="${config.exchangeName}")
    public void receive(String input) {
        System.out.println("   Receiver#receive input: " + input);
    }
}
```

Here's the first bit of the console output:

```
  .   ____          _            __
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.2.RELEASE)

2016-02-23 10:20:47.710  INFO 18804 --- [           main] c.i.logging.receiver.Application         : Starting Application on INT002520 with PID 18804 (C:\Users\matt.aspen\Documents\_logging\log-message-receiver2\target\classes started by matt.aspen in C:\Users\matt.aspen\Documents\_logging\log-message-receiver2)
2016-02-23 10:20:47.710  INFO 18804 --- [           main] c.i.logging.receiver.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-02-23 10:20:47.710 DEBUG 18804 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.intelligrated.logging.receiver.Application
2016-02-23 10:20:47.750 DEBUG 18804 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'classpath:/application.properties'
2016-02-23 10:20:47.750 DEBUG 18804 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped (empty) config file 'classpath:/application.properties' for profile default
2016-02-23 10:20:47.750  INFO 18804 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@679b62af: startup date [Tue Feb 23 10:20:47 PST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-02-23 10:20:48.482  INFO 18804 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$68858653] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
host localhost
userName guest
password guest
exchangeName from-logger-exchange
queueName from-logger-queue
queue.name from-logger-queue
exchange.name from-logger-exchange
binding Binding [destination=from-logger-queue, exchange=from-logger-exchange, routingKey=my.routing.key]
connectionFactory CachingConnectionFactory [channelCacheSize=1, host=localhost, port=5672, active=true connectionFactory]
2016-02-23 10:20:48.642  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: SimpleConnection@6239aba6 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/]
rabbitAdmin org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin@5f354bcf
2016-02-23 10:20:48.753 DEBUG 18804 --- [           main] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application Admin MBean registered with name 'org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication'
2016-02-23 10:20:48.998  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-02-23 10:20:49.208  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
2016-02-23 10:20:49.208  INFO 18804 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2016-02-23 10:20:49.218  WARN 18804 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:from-logger-exchange
2016-02-23 10:20:49.228  WARN 18804 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=3

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[from-logger-exchange]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:571) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:470) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1171) [spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:885) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:61) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:764) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:550) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'from-logger-exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'from-logger-exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:484) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:321) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:554) ~[amqp-client-3.5.7.jar:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted

2016-02-23 10:20:54.226  WARN 18804 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Failed to declare queue:from-logger-exchange
2016-02-23 10:20:54.226  WARN 18804 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Queue declaration failed; retries left=2
```

What's even more confusing is that when i look at http://localhost:15672/#/connections i see the connection, http://localhost:15672/#/channels i see the channel, http://localhost:15672/#/exchanges i see "from-logger-exchange", and http://localhost:15672/#/queues i see "from-logger-queue"

Answer (score 0):

One problem is your exchange is not a `@Bean`.

I get

```
reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'from.logging.exchange' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=20)
```

with your config. Adding `@Bean` to the exchange fixes it.

**EDIT**

Also (as Artem points out below), you have the wrong property on the listener

```
@RabbitListener(queues="${config.exchangeName}")
```

should be

```
@RabbitListener(queues="${config.queueName}")
```

Comment: `@RabbitListener(queues="${config.exchangeName}")` Point to the `TopicExchange`. Really not to the `queue`... Listener can listen only from the real `Queue`. Maybe `${config.queueName}` would be better ?..